# imagemap multiple tooltip reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I made an imagemap with area polygons which has tooltips over each polygon whilst the mouse is hovering over it.

I've also got a legend at the bottom of the image map, what I'd like to achieve is to whilst having the mouse over the specific item in the legend showing the tooltip on the specific polygon area.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be nice of you to post your code, but if you would like to accomplish this using javascript I could demonstrate it for you

Comment: I just want a basis/demonstration to follow if possible, thanks

Answer (score 0):

While its not possible to force the same behavior as the title attribute gives you can use either http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ or a css based tooltip http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/ to react to an onmouseover/onmouseleave event on your legend elements